# Checking whether two strings are a palindrome - ignoring and using case writing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, text, palindrome

What follows is a simple script. Basically, I'm experimenting with strings, and I want to check whether a string is a palindrome (ignoring lower upper case), and if it is reverse it with the same writing of the original string (upper- and lowercase):

```
input = "Repaper"
reverse = reversed(input)

if input == reverse:
    print(reverse)
```

I don't get any error warning - it's just no input?

Comment: You need to lower (or upper) the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, using `input` as a variable is **bad practice** as it's already a built-in function (see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). Sure, it doesn't hurt your code, but it also doesn't benefit you in any way! Why not call the string e.g. `input_string` or `in_str`?

---

As far as I understood you, you want to compare two strings - ignoring lower- and uppercase writing:

```
in_str = 'Anna'

#Ignoring lower-/uppercase
in_str = in_str.casefold()

#Reversing the string
rev_str = reversed(in_str)
```

Now it's important to know that the built-in function `reversed()`, which we've been using for now, returns a reverse iterator, so we shall (one example) compare via `list()`:

```
#Comparing the string and check whether it's a palindrome
if list(in_str) == list(rev_str):
    #Outputting the reversed string; for example via slicing
    print(in_str[::-1])
```

-> So for the example input `Anna`, the output would be `annA` which should be exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Oh, as another user, @Dani Masejo, has pointed out: Instead of `casefold()` you may also use `upper()` as the string could be checked with all-uppercase writing as well! With `casefold()` or `lower()` you turn the string into lowercase writing.

Answer (score 0):

given a string `a` and a string `b`

```
return a == b[::-1] # would return True if a and b are palindromes
```